# Forwarding DNS query from Linux to another two Windows DNS servers

Tags: dns, centos7, bind, forwarding, named

I have set up a linux server and configured the dns named service (LINDNS1). This will serve as the primary DNS for all internal clients. The only job it will do is to forward all the queries to the existing Windows DNS servers (WINDNS1 and WINDNS2).

So, when the client query goes to LINDNS1, it will forward the query to WINDNS1 if it can't find a record, it will forward the query to WINDNS2. If the record is in WINDNS2, it will answer the query.

I have set the forwarder settings on the dns configuration files. But it is not working.

```
named.conf #not much change here except for the standard settings.
         listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; LINDNS1 IP address; };
         allow-query { localhost; any; };  #I just put 'any' for now while it's in a testing phase.
         allow-query-cache { localhost; any; };
         recursion yes;
```

The forwarding configuration is set in the named.rfcxxxx.zone file. I have included the reverse zones as well.

```
zone "test.net" IN {
      type forward;
      forwarders { 1.1.1.1; 2.2.2.2; };
};
```

Clients don't have any problem issuing nslookup, LINDNS1 can respond and can query records in WINDNS1 (1.1.1.1). But when querying a record that is in WINDNS2 (2.2.2.2), it returns that it can't find the host.

Answer (score 0):

> So, when the client query goes to LINDNS1, it will forward the query to WINDNS1 if it can't find a record, it will forward the query to WINDNS2. If the record is in WINDNS2, it will answer the query.

No. When LINDNS receives the answer `NXDOMAIN` from WINDNS1 it has no reason to ask other servers again about this record.

In your case WINDNS2 will be queried only if WINDNS fails (server is down, named is not running, etc)